# react navigation back not working as it should

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a stack navigator defined as follows

```
const navigator=StackNavigator(
{
    HomeScreen:{screen:Home},
    newUserScreen1:{screen:newUser1},
    newUserScreen2:{screen:newUser2},
},
routeOptions
);
```

This is how the initial state is defined

```
initialState=Navigator.router.getStateForAction(Navigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('HomeScreen');
```

I can go from home to newUserScreenOne and calling `navigation.back()` from newUserScreen1 takes me back to home but when I go from newUserScreen1 to newUserScreen2 calling `navigation.back()` takes me back to HomeScreen. My understanding is that the screens are stacked on top of each other in stack navigator so calling `back()` from newUserScreen2 should show newUserScreen1. Is there anything that I am missing? Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is occurring when going from `Home > Screen1 > Screen2`, you should provide insight into how you're navigating to each. Are you doing something like...

#### From Home:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('newUserScreen1', {name: 'New User'});
```

#### From Screen1:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('newUserScreen2', {name: 'New User'});
```

#### From Screen2:

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```

If you're navigating as above, I think it should work for you.

Note, that you can also indicate a specific key to "goBack" to for finer control over which screen you return to. For more information, see the [React Navigation Docs | goBack()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#goBack-Close-the-active-screen-and-move-back)

Comment: That is exactly how I am navigating but that doesn't work.

Comment: I am using redux to manage state so the way these functions are executed is a little different for instance this is how i move from home screen to screen1: `Navigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:'newUserScreen1'}));`